# react-datepicker how do i increase the height of the inputbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

how do i increase height of datepicker input box ?

i am using "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

using inline css doesnt work

```
    <DatePicker 
              style={{root: {height: 7000} }}
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={onDateChange}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      selectsRange

          
              />
```

i am using "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

using inline css doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom class to your input

```
<DatePicker
    dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={selectDateHandler} 
    minDate={today}
    todayButton={"Today"}
    className="customInput"
/>
```

**css**

```
.customInput {
    height: 10px;
}
```